# Convert grams to kilo grams in javascript by clicking the button of kilograms

Tags: javascript, html

```
Input Grams(g):
    <input type="text" name="grams" id="grams"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="kilo()">Kilogram</button>
    <p id="convert"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function kilo(){

        }
```

Comment: multiply by 1024

Comment: no, wait ... 1000

Comment: @JaromandaX Seriously? I think you confused with Kilobytes, is it.

Comment: Divide by 1000. If you convert grams to kilograms you divide by 1000 (eg, 15g = 0.015Kg). If you convert kilograms to grams you multiply by 1000 (eg, 15Kg = 15,000g).

Comment: @JaromandaX i mean in my question is if the user input a grams by clicking the button of kilograms the amount will appear..

Comment: oh, and it's divide not multiply - I misread the original 2 lines of code :p

Comment: What is your real problem? I suppose the elementary school stuff you're currently asking, is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
Input Grams(g): <input type="text" name="grams" id="grams">
<br>
Results: <p id="convert"></p>

<button onclick="kilo()">Kilogram</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function kilo() {
        document.getElementById('convert').innerHTML =
            (document.getElementById('grams').value/1000 + "kg");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: but i have an <p id = "convert"></p> an you have result id

Comment: @CheskaMontemayor i have changed it

Comment: @CheskaMontemayor - I take it you want exact code that will work exactly, so you don't have to think about it at all

Comment: Has this solved your problem? @CheskaMontemayor . You dont have to put <button type="button"

Answer (score 1):

```
var ratio = 1000;

function kilo(grams) {
    return grams / ratio ;
}
```